# After upgrading from spring boot 2.6.6 to spring boot 3.0.2 the sftpoutboundgateway unable to perform Command.MV from remote sftp to remote sftp

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have been working on a spring boot migration from Tibco and my application requirement is to connect with a remote sftp server and perform the below operation,

1. perform COMMAND.LS from remote input DIR
2. perform COMMAND.MV from remote input to remote working.
3. Get the file data from the working DIR for processing to the client.
4. After completion performs COMMAND.MV the files from working to completed dir.

and I'm using the spring-integration-sftp framework for this
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-mv-command
Which is possible using the following
SFTP Outbound Gateway

I'm using a local sftp server setup to test the application and for local development
The following code absolutely works in spring boot 2.6.6

```
@Bean
    SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setPassword(asyncConfigProperty.getDstFtpPassword());
        factory.setHost(asyncConfigProperty.getDstFtpHost());
        factory.setUser(asyncConfigProperty.getDstFtpUserName());
        factory.setPort(asyncConfigProperty.getDstFtpPort());
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;

    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> cachingSftpSessionFactory()
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(sftpSessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpMoveCompletedFlow(
            @Qualifier("sftpInternalFactory") SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> cachingSftpSessionFactory) {
        return e -> {
            try {
                e.delay("3000").log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "MOVE.FILE.COMPLETED", Message::getPayload)
                        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "MOVE.FILE.COMPLETED", Message::getHeaders)
                        .handle(Sftp
                                .outboundGateway(sftpWorkingFileTemplate(cachingSftpSessionFactory),
                                        AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV, "payload")
                                .renameExpression("headers['dest_dir']" + " + " + "payload")
                                .fileExistsMode(org.springframework.integration.file.support.FileExistsMode.REPLACE));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "COMPLETE_MESSAGE_CHANNEL")
    MessageHandler CompleteMessageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> arg0) throws MessagingException {
                log.info("Message recieved COMPLETE_MESSAGE_CHANNEL" + "payload = " + arg0.getPayload() + "headers ="
                        + arg0.getHeaders());

                
                if (arg0 != null && arg0.getHeaders() != null) {
                    String fileName = (String) arg0.getHeaders().get(Const.GET_REMOTE_FILE_NAME);
                    
                    log.info("END OF THE FILE MOVE TO COMPLETE");
                    Map<String, String> mapObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    mapObj.put("dest_dir", asyncConfigProperty.getFtpCompletedDataDirectory());
                    gateway.moveCompleted(fileName, mapObj);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpMoveCompletedFlow.input")
    void moveCompleted(@Payload String srcFile, @Headers Map<String, String> map);
```

My expectation is here the AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV should move and replace the file from source to destination  irrespective of an existing file with the same name in destination.
Observed the AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV  and with FileExistMode.REPLACE is working as expected with Jsch session/spring boo 2.6.6 but it's not working as expected after upgrading to ssh session/spring boot 3.0.2

After upgrading the spring boot 3 the file having same name in completed dir is stuck in working dir.

1. input
2. working
3. completed

Observed, in spring boot 2.6.6 with Jsc session. In case PPV0311.txt is already available in completed then deleting file and then renaming '/working/PPV0311.txt' to '/completed/PPV0311.txt'

```
08:20:53.897 Debug SFTP: Getting item info on '/working/PPV0311.txt': success.
08:20:53.911 Debug SFTP: Opening file '/working/PPV0311.txt' (Open, Read): success.
08:20:53.927 Debug SFTP: Closing file '/working/PPV0311.txt': success.
08:20:54.256 Debug SFTP: Getting item info on '/completed': success.
08:20:54.263 Debug SFTP: Renaming '/working/PPV0311.txt' to '/completed/PPV0311.txt': failure.
08:20:54.271 Debug SFTP: Deleting file '/completed/PPV0311.txt': success.
08:20:54.277 Debug SFTP: Renaming '/working/PPV0311.txt' to '/completed/PPV0311.txt': success.
```

Observed, in spring boot 3.0.2 with SSH session. In case PPV0311.txt is already available in completed then the last two steps is different from above one as its only getting info it does not take care of deleting or renaming

```
08:32:00.596 Debug SFTP: Getting item info on '/working/PPV0311.txt': success.
08:32:00.602 Debug SFTP: Opening file '/working/PPV0311.txt' (Open, Read): success.
08:32:00.944 Debug SFTP: Closing file '/working/PPV0311.txt': success.
08:32:00.973 Debug SFTP: Getting item info on '/completed': success.
08:32:00.979 Debug SFTP: Getting item info on '/completed/PPV0311.txt': success.
```

Comment: Where you able to find any solving to it? because I'm facing the same issue.